# Oracle Sql Developer export slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running some queries with Oracle SQL Developer, and want to export the output to an csv file. But the export takes way too long, it seems to be re-running the whole query again. Here are my steps, please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

1. Run the query with 'Run Statement'
2. Results returned after 10 minutes, results shown in 'query result' underneath.
3. Right click the results, click 'export' and select 'csv' in export wizard.
4. Click Next, and Next to save the results.
5. Takes 10-30 minutes to output 10,000 rows data.

I understand there is a difference between showing results in grid, vs full results. But something seems to be wrong here and it is wasting too much of my time exporting data.

Thanks too all your help.

Answer (score 7):

It IS running the whole query again.

To avoid that, fetch all the results to the grid, and then EXPORT them.

Ctrl+End will do that.

I talk about this here 
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/how-to-export-sql-developer-query-results-without-re-running-the-query/

**But WHY does SQL Developer force the 2nd query execution**?

Good question.

If you do force all of the rows back into the grid, you are going to be consuming a decent amount of memory. Some query result sets are larger than others, and not all of us have 64 bit monsters to run our tools on. So, in order to conserve machine resources and memory, we just run the query again and write the data directly to the destination and bypass the data grid.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am running on MAC, what is the shortcut keys then?

Comment: probably cmd+End, or it might be cmd+PgDn

Comment: I checked 'shortcut keys' in preference setting, it is cmd + page down. But when i click those keys, the output has no change at all and it is still slow.

Comment: Show me your data grid - it should say - 10,000 rows fetched. And doing the export from there should be FAST. 10k rows is nothing

Comment: @wggbullet it's a [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh), not a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: The problem is, I cannot find any key equivalent to ctrl + end that can go to the end of the output result. I only find fn + right arrow, which fetches 50 rows a time. So if there are 10,000 rows, i have to hold the keys 200 times to fetch all the data.

Comment: I find that ctl+end'ing to the bottom of an expensive query brings my machine to a crawl (occupying 100% of CPU). exporting from the top doesn't have this problem (for me)